# Swift Bluetooth singleton Class handler

Tags: swift, bluetooth, core-bluetooth

hi i hvae a bluetooth singleton class, i want to pass my ble connect status to my viewcontroller when updatevalue. i think need some listener.

my Bluetooth class is here

```
class Bluetooth:NSObject, CBCentralManagerDelegate, CBPeripheralDelegate {

static var instance = Bluetooth()
func initBluetoothSingleton(){}

func peripheral(_ peripheral: CBPeripheral, didUpdateValueFor characteristic: CBCharacteristic, error: Error?) {
    
    if characteristic.uuid == BLE_WIFI_EVENT_CHARACTERISTIC_CBUUID {
        let wifiEvent = ReadWiFiEvent(using: characteristic)
        if(wifiEvent == "connect"){
            // i want to pass data to my viewcontroller to show alert
        }
    }
}
func handlerBleStatus(completion: (status:String) -> ()) {
    completion(status: "connect")
}
```

and my viewcontroller is like this in viewdidload or somewhere

```
Bluetooth.instance.handlerBleStatus { (status) in
    print(status)  //how to set a listener here
}
```

i want set a listener when my ble updatevalue then show alert let user know the status
is this situation need user protocol?

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can send values in multiple ways. Using protocols, closures, or notification center.

I believe using a closure would work fine for your case.

Define a variable in the `Bluetooth` class

```
static var instance = Bluetooth()
var handleBleStatus: ((String) -> Void)?
```

Set the closure in your view controller/model.

```
Bluetooth.instance.handleBleStatus = { value in 
    print(value)
    // TODO: Display alert
}
```

Then you can send values from the `Bluetooth` class using the closure. The view you set the closure variable will get the update.

```
if(wifiEvent == "connect"){
    // i want to pass data to my viewcontroller to show alert
    handleBleStatus?("Status: Connected")
}
```